# want to create dyanmic chtml::dropdownlist in jquery

Tags: jquery, yii

I need to create dropdown list dynamically in jquery. I tried with below code but giving error as below section

```
 var row = activity_row_count;
function addNewRow(){
    <?php $category_list=(json_decode($json_category_list));?>   
    var newRow = jQuery('<tr><td><?php  echo CHtml::dropDownList('listname', '', array('M' => 'Male', 'F' => 'Female')); ?></td><td><input type="text" name="actual_hrs"/></td></tr>');
    jQuery('#new_activity').append(newRow);
    row++;
    }
```

giving error as

```
SyntaxError: unterminated string literal
var newRow = jQuery('<tr><td><select name="listname1" id="listname1">
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem is not related to yii. It's because of incorrect using of jquery. You did not close `<td>`,`<tr>` and `<select>` tags. Also you forgot to close your string!
Try this:

```
jQuery('<tr><td><select name="listname1" id="listname1"></select></td></tr>')
```

Comment: its not an closing issue. i have mentioned the error which I pasted from firebug